# Is it possible to add Mac outlook custom addin for Desktop Mac

Tags: macos, outlook-addin, yeoman-generator, outlook-mac

I have already created simple Mac outlook add in using yeoman tool from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
so my question is how to add this add ins on desktop Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sideload add-in by clicking on **Get Add-Ins** in home tab pane of outlook and upload custom add-in with a manifest file.

Click on Get Add-ins[image]

Select My Add in -> Upload custom add in manifest file